# Chat with another pc with react chat-app and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I followed a youtube tutorial on making a chat app with react js and socket.io. It is complete and works perfectly, but only on the pc, the project is running on. What I need is the application to chat with another pc the project is working on, it could be on the same network, for starters. The front-end is separate and is made with react js. 
I tried adding a dummy IP to where I specify the port it will run on, but didn't work. 
Any ideas? What am I missing here? 
Here's the code to the `server.js` which is in plain `node js`:

```
const port = 5000 || '0.0.0.0' <--- Ignore the dummy IP kindly, didn't work, thought it was worth a try
const io = require('socket.io')(port)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  const id = socket.handshake.query.id
  socket.join(id)
  console.log("Listening at " + port)

  socket.on('send-message', ({ recipients, text }) => {
    recipients.forEach(recipient => {
      const newRecipients = recipients.filter(r => r !== recipient)
      newRecipients.push(id)
      socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit('receive-message', {
        recipients: newRecipients, sender: id, text
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If anybody finds other relevant questions that can help, you can share those too.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you look into deploying your chat app on something like Heroku or Firebase, which will provide you a 3rd-party non-localhost link that other PCs and users can go to in order to access your chat app.
Alternatively, you can use something like https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel to have other PCs access your localhost

Comment: Thanks for the localtunnel suggestion, it is really a good tool.

Comment: Somewhere on discord, I got this suggestion:  ```You need to connect to the local IP of that computer on your network or host it online```  
What does connecting to local IP mean, and how is it done?

Comment: The github repo for localtunnel is an example of a way of exposing your localhost to allow other users to access it. Is there any reason why you are not choosing to host your site online on a cloud provider (e.g., netlify, heroku, firebase)?

Comment: I tried to host the server, but it didn't work